# Change Heading for Access subform when copying and pasting into Excel

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2010 form with a subform that is displayed in datasheet view.  The users want to be able to select and copy the rows from the subform and when they paste into Excel they want the table header to be the value from the main form. Currently it just uses the name of the subform.  Is there a way to set this to something else?

Here is what currently shows up in Excel after I paste the copied grid.  What I want to have displayed instead of fsubFYTBSummary is a field from the parent record of the form that invoked the subfrom.  Is there a way to set this?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Is "the table header" the headings of the columns? Or something else? What is "the value from the main form"? Can you add a screenshot of the form and of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. The copied name is the name of the source object, not the subform control (that would be changeable).

Actually I'm surprised you see this name in Excel. I only see it when pasting a grid to Word or an Email, where the HTML clipboard format is used. The name is the table caption.

You can use http://freeclipboardviewer.com/ (portable) to see the various formats of clipboard contents.

Comment: When I paste onto Excel if I choose "Match Destination Formatting" I get the name of the subform as a row above the column headers like in my screen shot.

Comment: I tried looking at the clipboard contents with the clipboardviewer application and it shows that the subform name is the <Title> tag when I select HTML format.  Any way to change this via code?

Comment: @Paul: I don't see a feasible way. Even if there would be, when would you call this code? Copying something from a datasheet or form in Access doesn't trigger any events.